# Convergence of a sequence in R implies convergence of another sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R}, \left\|  \cdot  \right\|_{2})$ be a metric space equipped with the Euclidean metric and:

$$\ a_{n}\to a$$ a sequence converging to a. Then $\forall p\gt 0$ show that:

$$\ p^{a_{n}}\to p^{a}$$

I've been able to show that:
$$\left|  p^{a_{n}}- p^{a}\right|=p^{a}\left|  p^{a_{n}-a}- 1\right|$$

and I intuitively understand that the second term is arbitrarily close to zero but I cannot formalise my thought.

Comment: $p^x$ is continuous $\implies$ sequentially continuous so it "preserves" convergent sequences.

Comment: I would like to prove the result without using continuity

Comment: Yes but when you say that the secondo term tends to zero you are implicitly saying "Because $p^x$ is continuous, $p^0=1$ and $a_n\to a$ then $p^{a_n-a}\to p^0=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proof without using continuity. We use only the definition of limit.

As $a_n \xrightarrow{n\to +\infty} a$, then for all $\epsilon_0>0$, there exists $N_0$ such that for all $n>N_0$, we hava $|a_n-a|<\epsilon_0$.
$$\tag{1}$$

Now, for the sequence $p^{a_n}$, for all $\epsilon_1>0$, we need to find $N_1$ such that for all $n>N_1$ :
$$|p^{a_n}-p^{a}|<\epsilon_1 \tag{2}$$

We have
$$\begin{align}
(2) &\Longleftrightarrow p^a|p^{a_n^-a}-1|<\epsilon_1    \\
 &\Longleftrightarrow |p^{a_n-a}-1|<p^{-a}\epsilon_1    \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \ln(1-p^{-a}\epsilon_1)<a_n-a<\ln(1+p^{-a}\epsilon_1) \\
\end{align} \tag{3}$$

From $(1)$,  choose $\epsilon_0$ satisfying

- $\epsilon_0<\ln(1+p^{-a}\epsilon_1)$  and
- $\ln(1-p^{-a}\epsilon_1) < -\epsilon_0$

or $\epsilon_0 < \min\{\ln(1+p^{-a}\epsilon_1), -\ln(1-p^{-a}\epsilon_1)   \}$

and by choosing $N_1 = N_0$, for all $n>N_1 = N_0$, we have $(3)$ holds true.

We can conclude that $p^{a_n} \xrightarrow{n\to +\infty} p^a$

Comment: thank you, that's what I was trying to prove

Comment: @iki you’re welcome. And please dont forget to accept the answer :)